# Icecast stream autheticastion inside url

Tags: authentication, audio-streaming, icecast, internet-radio

I configured listener authentication according to the manual:
https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.0/auth.html
Everything is working, except that I need to be able to pass credentials in URL http://user:hackme@mystream.aac but Icecast is ignoring it.
Yes I know that's a bad way to pass password but that's a working solution and I can't change it.

Comment: `http://user:hackme@icecast.example.com/mystream.aac` is probably closer to what you want.  If that's what you meant, then show us the relevant config so we can help you figure out what's wrong.  And, what specifically do you mean by, "Icecast is ignoring it"?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers do not pass the user:password part of the URLs as a security precaution. I confirmed that using Safari for example, the user:pass is not passed on to the host (i.e. Icecast).

You can test this with something like cURL, which will let you pass authentication that way. But most browsers are not allowing those kinds of URLs with embedded authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers mean in this case: All browsers that use the blink engine. Firefox (and I've been told) also some versions of Safari still support it and together with https I also don't see a security risk with that. That's why I currently recommend to use firefox to my users/customers for this specific purpose and if it must be a browser (vlc, mplayer, mpv and most other audio/video player software also support it)